# Installer not removing previous versions

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I have an app. In-order to install the app I'm using a simple Deployment Project with parameters like this:

```
DetectNewerInstalledVersion = true  
InstallAllUsers = true  
ProductCode = GUID (changing with version)  
RemovePreviousVersions = true  
UpgradeCode = GUID (Allways the same)  
Version = 1.0.5 (changing with each deployment).
```

Problem is, **this installer(Deployment Project) never removes previous versions**. It installs on top and windows shows that, I have 2 versions of my program(i.e, app which I installed) but none of theme work correctly.

---

**EDIT**
I added one line to assemblyInfo:  but it still changes nothing. After analyzing my problem more deeply, i realized that installer changes most of the files in Program Files folder, but it removes icon from Desktop and record from registry. After installing on top, i can't even remove application, because i cannot see it in Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features.
If i install on top, i am not able to use program. But if i run it from program files folder it works (newer version). If i install it twice, everything is ok (while installing it second time, wizard asks to repair or remove program).
Maybe this time somebody has something else to suggest?
Solutions for MSI files does not suit me, because final installer is EXE file.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what is the problem , because you have mentioned that both versions are not working correctly??, I mean when you click the both version does not open the app or getting crash while opening the app? or some other problem?

Comment: @Sankar: last time I had this problem, some installer components would install correctly, and some would be left from the previous version, so usually there would be mixed up assembly versions.

Comment: > "simple Deployment Project" - you mean this that does not exist anymore in a modern Visual studio version (2012)? Have you tried using WIX, which is the open source replacement from Microsoft and allows full / detailed control? Have you tried installing with a log file generation and checking what the MSI log says when you "upgrade"?

Comment: @Groo: Thanks for clarifying me, i want to understand the problem of the user, so that i can help or him not? Thanks Groo once again

Comment: @Sankar: of course, I didn't think you were bashing the OP, that's just my experience (and I had this problem with WiX, not VS deployment project).

Comment: @Groo: Well, May be we can wait until this Question posted user  replay, so that we can get an idea and  convey solution or suggestion to the user.

Comment: Also mention how you are changing the version with each deployment

Comment: Ok, i still gave this problem. I tried lots of solutions, but it still doesn't work. I added AssemblyFileVersion to AssemblyInfo. I even tried to change version from 1.0.0.0 to 1.1.0.0 but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time but it is very simple.

1. Go to manage VS Extensions and install 'Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project' v0.9.9
2. Right click on your installer project and go to properties. Keep the UpgradeCode variable in the properties window the same for different versions of the same product.
3. Change your ProductCode variable between different builds.
4. Now when you install the product with the same UpgradeCode already on the system, the installer will upgrade your existing product and you will only have one program in the Add/Remove window.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.  I worked around it by uninstalling the old version before calling the installer for the new version.

This code will uninstall an installed Product by it's ProductCode:

```
  try
  {
     Process p = new Process();
     p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     p.StartInfo.FileName = "MsiExec.exe";
     p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/x{53A13817-D52F-4F16-AE27-68D01DA0A656} /passive";
     p.Start();
     p.WaitForExit();
  }
  catch
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Unable to uninstall Application.  Manually uninstall/reinstall to update.");
  }
```

Just remember to replace my Product Code with yours.  The nice part is that if the product is not installed, it does nothing.

Comment: And where should i put this? in custom actions?